# Make gnome-terminal show the command running as title

Tags: gnome-terminal

I want the name of command running , e.g unzip to be visible through the title bar of gnome-terminal , but it seems to be impossible , if the application running doesn't set a title explicitly , even though I choose 'Replace initial title' option in the profile dialog.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a more complete solution actually taking care of bash-completion spamming garbage.

To be clear: I did nothing on my own here but research. All credit goes to [Marius Gedminas](http://mg.pov.lt/blog/bash-prompt.html).

This works perfectly for me with Gnome-Terminal/Terminator (put it in your .bashrc or somewhere that's getting sourced)

```
# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;${USER}@${HOSTNAME}: ${PWD}\007"'

    # Show the currently running command in the terminal title:
    # http://www.davidpashley.com/articles/xterm-titles-with-bash.html
    show_command_in_title_bar()
    {
        case "$BASH_COMMAND" in
            *\033]0*)
                # The command is trying to set the title bar as well;
                # this is most likely the execution of $PROMPT_COMMAND.
                # In any case nested escapes confuse the terminal, so don't
                # output them.
                ;;
            *)
                echo -ne "\033]0;${USER}@${HOSTNAME}: ${BASH_COMMAND}\007"
                ;;
        esac
    }
    trap show_command_in_title_bar DEBUG
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac
```

Also this is a [cross-post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10546217/how-to-view-process-name-in-terminal-emulator-tab-or-title-bar) because I just found out about it and wanted to share and I think it's useful here as well.

Comment: Don't do this without guarding the trap with a test like [ -n "$PS1" ] or your escape sequences will baffle scripts!

Comment: I've found using `local this_command=$(HISTTIMEFORMAT= history 1 | sed -e "s/^[ ]*[0-9]*[ ]*//");` instead of $BASH_COMMAND cleaner as it shows aliases in their original unexpanded form.

Comment: Hmm... I'm going to try to get this to display the vim buffer if vim is the command.

Answer (score 10):

This has been sort of answered [here](https://superuser.com/questions/175799/does-bash-have-a-hook-that-is-run-before-executing-a-command).

- `trap 'command' DEBUG` makes bash run `command` before every command.
- `echo -ne "\033]0;Title\007"` changes the title to "Title"
- `$BASH_COMMAND` contains the command being run.

Combining these we get

```
trap 'echo -ne "\033]0;$BASH_COMMAND\007" > /dev/stderr' DEBUG
```

Then we just have to reset the title after we complete the command. I did this by setting `$PS1` to change the title to the current path.

tl;dr: Add these two lines (in this order, otherwise I got a garbled prompt) to the bottom of `~/.bashrc`

```
PS1="\033]0;\w\007${PS1}"
trap 'echo -ne "\033]0;$BASH_COMMAND\007" > /dev/stderr' DEBUG
```

Edit: Your `$PS1` might already change the title, in which case only the last line is needed.

Comment: Why the redirection to stderr?