# How do I run a command before or after every command written in the console?

Tags: command-line, bash

I want to run a command before and after every single command that gets executed in a terminal (i.e. `clear` before and then `reset`). I want this to happen automatically and not with a short alias or similar.

I have looked into bashrc and /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion although the latter seems to be just for the auto completion feature with the <kbd>Tab</kbd>?

Where should I make my changes?

Comment: You want to run a command before each command, what will be run before that command? It's a recursion here

Comment: @Anwar I meant run a command before each command written in the console.

Comment: That's a good opportunity to switch to Zsh, which can do this natively. In Bash it requires some tinkering; see http://superuser.com/questions/175799/does-bash-have-a-hook-that-is-run-before-executing-a-command

Comment: Also see: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44713/can-i-configure-bash-to-execute-clear-before-every-command-typed-in-the-consol

Comment: In zsh you can simply define a function:  precmd() { echo "Hi" ; }

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your `.bashrc`:

```
function process_command() {
  ... do something with $BASH_COMMAND ...
}
trap process_command DEBUG
```

For a good example see "[Make gnome-terminal show the command running as title](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126737/make-gnome-terminal-show-the-command-running-as-title)" on AskUbuntu.

To solve the original poster's request to run `clear` before the command and `reset` after the command, add to `.bashrc`:

```
function before_command() { 
  case "$BASH_COMMAND" in
        $PROMPT_COMMAND)
          ;;
       *)
          clear;
  esac
}

function before_prompt() { reset ; }

trap before_command DEBUG
PROMPT_COMMAND=before_prompt
```

In `man bash` look for `PROMPT_COMMAND` and `trap .-lp`.

Comment: Would it be `{ clear; $BASH_COMMAND; reset; }` ?

Comment: No. Please read the provided link and the manual. You cannot execute `$BASH_COMMAND`, it's provided for informative purposes only. What the original poster asked can be done by clearing the screen in a function called just before executing a command, and resetting the terminal in a function run before outputting the prompt. I have edited the answer to provide an example.

Comment: @AlexP your answer is useful, however, I have tried it with the command `date` and found the following: Hitting enter correctly runs before_command and before_prompt. However, if I write the command `ls` and then hit enter, the before_command runs twice, once before and once after `ls`. The command before_prompt correctly runs once after `ls`. I'm still looking for a complete solution for this, any tips are much appreciated.

Comment: The function set as a DEBUG trap will run before _any_ command is executed, which means that it will also run before $PROMPT_COMMAND. You can test $BASH_COMMAND to see whether the command to be run is $PROMPT_COMMAND or not.